# Pointwise and uniform convergence of a piecewise sequence of functions on the closed, punctured disk, $\overline{D}\prime(0,1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

Consider the sequence of functions $$f_n(z) = 
\begin{cases}
n,  & \text{if $0<|z|\leq\frac{1}{n}$} \\
\frac{1}{z^4}, & \text{if $\frac{1}{n}<|z|\leq1$}
\end{cases}
$$
for $n\geq 1$, on the closed, punctured disk, $\overline{D}\prime(0,1) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0<|z|\leq1\}$.

(i) Prove that $f_n(z)$ converges pointwise to a functions $f(z)$ and determine this function.

(ii) Is the convergence uniform?

For part (i) I've guessed that $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^4}$ and I am trying to prove this by showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty}|f_n(z)-f(z)| = 0$. I've managed to do this for the case when $\frac{1}{n}<|z|\leq1$ as $\lim_{n \to \infty}|f_n(z)-f(z)| = \lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{1}{z^4}-\frac{1}{z^4}| = 0$ in that case.
However, for the case when $0<|z|\leq\frac{1}{n}$ I haven't had much luck. Thus far for this case I have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}|f_n(z)-f(z)| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|n-\frac{1}{z^4}\right| \leq n + \frac{1}{|z|^4}$$ and as $|z| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ in this case we have that $n-\frac{1}{|z|^4} \leq n-n^4$. But I've no ideas about where to from here since $n-n^4 \to -\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

I've also made an attempt at part (ii) but haven't had any luck with that either.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to note that for $n\to \infty$, the interval $0 < |z| \le 1/n$ "crumbles" to the point $0$, where the function is undefined.

In particular, given $z\in \Bbb{C}$, you have that:
$$n > 1/|z| \implies |f_n(z) - z^{-4}| = 0$$
So the sequence converges pointwise. So for any $z$ we can find an $n$ such that for all subsequent $n$, the two functions are the same.

EDIT: It does not converge uniformly, since for all $M>0$:
$$n \ge 1 \implies \sup_{z \in D} |f_n(z) - z^{-4}| \ge M$$
As you can clearly see, since the supremum of $f_n$ over the disk is $n^4$ while the supremum $z^{-4}$ is infinite. The absolute value of their difference is, again, infinite in supremum.

Comment: Thank you. I just don't understand where the $n^4$ in your disproof of uniform convergence comes from.

Comment: I forgot to mention $n^4$ is the modulus of the supremum. The supremum as a complex number on $\Bbb{C}$ does not exist since it's not an ordered field. Of course you can define the supremum only if you're talking about the moduli, since they're real numbers.

Comment: But $\sup_{z \in \overline{D}\prime(0,1)} |f_n(z) - z^{-4}| = \sup_{z \in \overline{D}\prime(0,1)}|\frac{1}{z^4} - \frac{1}{z^4}| = 0$. I don't understand how this equals $n^4$.

Comment: No, the modulus of just $f_n$ is $n^4$ in supremum...

Comment: Also, that sup is equal to zero only if you look solely at the region $1/n < |z| \le 1$, otherwise it's infinite.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well thank you for taking the time.